# Nifi TailFile Processor timeout

Tags: java, runtimeexception, apache-nifi

I'm trying to run a tailfile that always starts at the bottom of the file it tails.  When I start the processor I keep getting this Error:

> 2016-09-26 15:13:23,973 ERROR [StandardProcessScheduler Thread-7] o.a.nifi.processors.standard.TailFile  java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Timed out while executing one of processor's OnScheduled task.    at
>   org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.invokeTaskAsCancelableFuture(StandardProcessorNode.java:1412)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.access$100(StandardProcessorNode.java:96)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode$1.run(StandardProcessorNode.java:1240)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   [na:1.8.0_101]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   [na:1.8.0_101]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>   [na:1.8.0_101]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>   [na:1.8.0_101]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [na:1.8.0_101]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [na:1.8.0_101]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   [na:1.8.0_101] Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
>   [na:1.8.0_101]    at
>   org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.invokeTaskAsCancelableFuture(StandardProcessorNode.java:1397)
>   ~[na:na]  ... 9 common frames omitted

I have set the "Run Schedule" to 5 seconds.  Do you have any idea as to what's happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your NiFi clustered? It seems like the onScheduled method of the processor is hanging on something and exceeding a time limit. That method loads the previous state of the processor. If NiFi is standalone that comes from a local file, if clustered it comes from ZooKeeper.

Comment: It's not clustered.  So what you're saying is that a local file from NiFi is creating issues?  I'm not sure I see why, this is a fresh NiFi install and it is only reading the end of a file.  Does it return an error if the file has not been updated in the last 5 seconds?

Comment: I was asking if it was clustered to see if it could have been hanging trying to connect to ZooKeeper to retrieve state information, but since it is stand alone we can rule that out. I'm not sure why there would be an issue accessing the local filesystem.

Comment: Thanks!  I reinstalled Nifi and the problem has gone away, will see if it comes back.  But Thanks a lot!